# How to cache image in picasso without load it to ImageView?

Tags: android, picasso

I developed my own AD SDK (like admob) and use picasso for loading images . 
my purpose is prevent user see blank imageview or placeholder while image is loading therefor I want load images in an IntentService to sure when activity started user see image without waiting .
how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more? You don't want you users to see a blank, or a placer holder, but you image without even been loaded?

Comment: All thing that I want to achieve is Picasso cache image without showing
then I can load that image immediately where i want to show

Comment: Load picasso image into a Target, ie a bitmap, cache it on sd card or in any other encoded format.

Comment: Picasso need to be attached into imageview and using Target can't help

Comment: did you find any soluion?

Comment: sadly not yet , but it seems best solution is using another way like download image with okhttp